# Ext.getCmp not returning current value of html editor

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I'm getting inconstant results using Ext.getCmp on my htmlEditor.

I'm noticing that it is returning the value of the property on page load but not the updated value.

```
onSubmitBtnClick: function () {

        var notes = Ext.getCmp('notes').value; 
      // this value is not the current value in the editor. 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.value` is configuration of what the field initializes with. Try `.getValue(`) instead.

```
onSubmitBtnClick: function () {

    var notes = Ext.getCmp('notes').getValue(); 
}
```